# Запятая после «так»

Tags: запятая

Нужна ли запятая после «так» в данном предложение: "Вот так попросишь человека вынести мусор, а он исчез."?
Если нужна, объясните – почему? Если не нужна, то опять же – почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, это устойчивая грамматическая конструкция.

ПРИМЕРЫ

Вот так возьмешь да и сойдешь с ума… [Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана (1938-1944)].

Вот так подумаешь и сообразишь...

Comment: Большое спасибо.